# How to access IMvxLog during iOS app launch

Tags: ios, mvvmcross

I'm using MvvmCross (6) for a Xamarin Forms application.
I need to write diagnostic logs during launch.

The IMvxLog service needs to be resolved via the Mvx.IoCProvider.
However, the IoCProvider is not yet available within WillFinishLaunching or FinishedLaunching (the singleton is null).

What is the expected MvvmCross mechanism to write to the log file during these methods?

Comment: You should be able to retrieve the logger with `Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxLog>();` as soon as `InitializePrimary()` has been invoked on your `MvxIosSetup` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

MvvmCross initializes the IoC Provider in the InitializePrimary() method defined in MvxSetup (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/44a37969059a81f26883c193a5ecf7f2ec88c9d8/MvvmCross/Core/MvxSetup.cs#L70)

Following the call stack up from there, that method is eventually called indirectly by this line in the FinishedLaunching method:

```
MvxIosSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(this, Window).EnsureInitialized()
```

So the earliest point where you can access the IMvxLog service via the IoC Provider is in FinishedLaunching after the base.FinishedLaunching() method is called.

Looks like the UIWindow is a dependency to initialize MvvmCross, so you may not be able to move built-in IoC initialization any earlier than that. You'll probably need to initialize the object manually and then register that instance once IoC initialized